# How to create down arrow hover effect using css

Tags: html, css

I have a rectangular bar that goes over the screen horizontally.

```
#rcorners1 {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #00CCFF;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 1210px;
    height: 10px;  
    line-height: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;   
}

<h2 id="rcorners1"><font color = "#000066"> &nbsp;&nbsp;Applications:</font></h2>
```

I want to add a hover effect such that whenever someone hovers over it, an triangle arrow pointing down comes.

Can anyone help me how to do it?

Comment: Note: Consider not using `font` as it's deprecated - you want to separate your style from your content.   Also, use classes whenever possible.

Comment: Do you want to display a triangle instead of existing rectangular screen or do you want to locate triangle below during hover effect?

Comment: Where do you want this triangle arrow to appear and how big a triangle are you looking for?

Comment: Hi, I want to locate the triangle below during hover effect and to be place on the left side of the bar.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple trick:

1. Place the triangle arrow on the page and hide it
2. On hover (via css), show the element

**Sample HTML:**

```
<h2 id="rcorners1">
    Applications
    <span class="hidden pull-right">&#9660;</span> <!-- your down triangle -->
</h2>
```

**Sample CSS**

```
/* Magic sauce */
#rcorners1:hover .hidden {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Utilities */
.hidden     { display: none; }
```

**Demo:** **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkcd82kx/)**

Note: Instead of `display`, you can also use `visibility` to manipulate the triangle's rendering on hover.

Comment: Hi, this does do what I'm asking for. I basically want the triangle to pop out downward on hover.